# “COVID-19 changed / has changed / has been changing the everyday life of people”

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect

This is for the translation of a bachelor thesis and we have different opinions on the use of the word "change".

Which is correct?

> COVID-19 changed / has changed / has been changing the everyday life of people.

1st person says: *changed*  means life changed in March and is changed since then.
2nd person thinks: *has changed* is stronger

I personally think: *has been changing* means that the changes have not come to an end and we are still dealing with it and new changes are communicated on a daily basis.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic If this is for a thesis, use capital letters for the term

Comment: I'd get rid of "the" and "people" and say **[our] everyday life** or use the genitive construction : **people's everyday lives**

Comment: You want to say different things, so picking different tenses isn’t surprising. That’s the English part done. As for the philosophical issue regarding which of you is right about COVID-19, that would be a matter of debate.